# Gmail priority inbox won't let me change inbox sections. Help?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, priority-inbox

I have a filter for important, unread and starred. Every time I try to change my Gmail priority inbox to the corresponding label, it changes to: "All Everything Else." It doesn't matter if I try inbox #1, 2 or 3.

Please advise.